# Problema ao alterar telas com Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewcontroller

estou com pequeno problema, a minha App usa a Navigation Controller e um View controller, tenho segues declaradas que fazem a ponte entre as cells.

Ao executar o app inicia no Navigation Controller e quando clico em dos itens da cell vai ate ao e exibe o item clicado na View controller.

E ao voltar, volta duas vezes no Navigation Controller o que me parece ter 2 Root View Controller.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? 
Desde ja meu obrigado.

[image: Print da tela]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Anselmo, o que você quis dizer com "volta duas vezes"? Não entendi...

Comment: Quero dizer o seguinte: quando estou na table view com itens na lista, e escolho qualquer um. Vou numa single view com o item escolhido.  Ao voltar para a table view dos itens ele volta duas vezes. Como se voltasse para table view e depois para navigation controller

Comment: Adicionei mais print

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de você estar clicando duas vezes no item? Isso já aconteceu comigo... Se você clica duas vezes e não tem nenhuma proteção quanto a isso, ele vai duas vezes para a página de destino e depois tem que voltar duas vezes... Se não for isso, pode postar o código?

Comment: Certamente não estou a clicar 2x no item, vou dar uma olhada no código

Comment: Você está provavelmente stacking outro view controller em vez de fazer o segue da maneira correta. Só dá pra ter certeza se você postar o seu código mostrando como é que você tá navegando de um controller para o outro.

Comment: Vou postar o código, mas pra já apenas tenho uma segue que liga a Cell a table view controller dos detalhes dos itens da lista

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se você não está chamando um performSegue antes e depois chamando outro evento ao selecionar na tableview. Mas se puder, poste o código. Já tive problema parecido, isso geralmente acontece quando usamos muitos callbacks e esquecemos de "finalizar" a view anterior.

Comment: Legal você querer ajudar, mas você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [um pouco mais de pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor utilize o campo de resposta somente para postar uma solução ao problema de que a pergunta trata.